# How can I split a polygon set with a line set using PostgreSQL recursive queries?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, splitting

I have a simple polygon layer `GEOMETRY(POLYGON,4326)` and a simple line layer `GEOMETRY(LINESTRING, 4326)`. I want to find all split areas. I am using PostGIS 2.0.

[image]

I am using following PL/pgSQL procedure:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE cursor_tmp (geom GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4326));

DO $$
DECLARE
  _geom GEOMETRY(LINESTRING, 4326);
  _curs CURSOR FOR SELECT geom FROM blades;

BEGIN
  OPEN _curs;
  LOOP
    FETCH
    _curs INTO _geom;
    EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND;

    TRUNCATE TABLE cursor_tmp;

    INSERT INTO cursor_tmp
      SELECT (ST_Dump(
          ST_CollectionExtract(
              ST_MakeValid(ST_Split(poly.geom, _geom))
              , 3))).geom :: GEOMETRY(POLYGON, 4326) geom
      FROM poly
      WHERE st_intersects(_geom, poly.geom);

    DELETE FROM poly WHERE st_intersects(_geom, geom);

    INSERT INTO poly SELECT * FROM cursor_tmp;

  END LOOP;
  CLOSE _curs;
END $$;
```

This gives me the desired results:

[image]

A colleague suggested that there might be a more elegant solution to this problem using PostgreSQL recursive queries. The problem is that I have zero knowledge of recursive queries.

Is it worth investigating? Will a recursive query be able to do this process?

Comment: do I get this right, blue is the line and red the polygons? if you use st_split with one linestring (or a union of all linestrings via subquery) on your set of polygons, it should split them where possible without the need for recursion, no? or what exactly do you want to find/extract (I don't really get the condition for the red area in your result...)?

Comment: That is right. But, Splitting a polygon by a multi-line string is not supported in PostGIS.

Comment: ah okay, no it's not..you said 'simple line layer' and I thought you meant no multi geoms. also I should have said 'merged' instead of 'union', since that guarantees a collection of possible simple geoms

Comment: Not a recursive query, but I'd consider dumping your polygons to lines, combining them with your existing lines, and polygonizing the output. (Assumes that I'm understanding the problem correctly, and that everything fits in memory.)